# Scripts in webview not working propely

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to show a website in my webview, this is my code:

```
webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.wb);
        WebSettings webSettings=webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webSettings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.4; Galaxy Nexus Build/IMM76B) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.133 Mobile Safari/535.19");
        webView.loadUrl("http://qoo724.ir/");
```

When I open the website inside google chrome or browser in my phone, every thing works fine but when I open it with my app, some parts not working properly, those parts works with jquery and ajax.

How can I find the problem ? how can I make my website to fully support javascipts?

Answer (score 0):

dont place your javascript in the html code

i also faced the problem and resolved it after i loaded it dynamically with java in android

have a look at the sample code

```
yourWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

   public void onPageFinished(final WebView webview, String url) {
       String yourJavaScriptCode = "alert('its working');";
       //now this is impoortnat please dont ignore it
       if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
          webview.evaluateJavascript(yourJavaScriptCode , null);
       } else {
          webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){" + yourJavaScriptCode + "})()");
       }
   }
});
```

query more if you have any doubt in excution of the code